# Unable to open web service tester pages (Netbeans 8.2/Tomcat 8.5.84)

Tags: javascript, web-services, tomcat, netbeans

When I try to "Test Web Service" in the project I'm developing, I get this message:

[image: Error message]

I found someone with a similar issue that I have but they use GlassFish, but Netbeans doesn't let me install GlassFish (I was going to originally use it but I got this problem)

I've tried:

- Reinstalling everything
- Using Apache Netbeans and Tomcat's latest versions respectively
- Reinstalling XAMPP with the other apps
- Reinstalling JKD 8 with the other apps
- Creating different users in tomcat-users.xml
- Installing Tomcat through .zip and Windows Installer
- Cleaning everything the programs leave behind before reinstalling

I've tried some solutions I found in Youtube and on Stack Overflow / other sites but I can't find any answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've removed your "please help me" clause because ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Please give [ask] a read, and write a clear, focused question. Please also [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: Thanks! I think I deviate from the important point, you focused it a lot better!

Comment: More information is needed. [1] Restart Tomcat. [2] Rebuild and redeploy your project to Tomcat [3] Generate the error message shown in your question. [4] Update your question with the content of Tomcat's log for that session. Also, you have tagged your question with "javascript" - should that be "java" instead?